# Is it possible to find a group based on its content but with alternatives?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm experimenting a bit with the regex and in particular with `groups`. Let's suppose I have the following text

```
I like blue. Do you like red?
I like blue. Do you like blue?
I like red. Do you like blue?

I like red. Do you like red?
```

I know that the referenced group `g{1}` matches the exact text but I was wondering if there is a way, using groups, to match all my lines even of the 2 colours are different.

Atm my regex is `I like (blue|red). Do you like \g{1}\?`

Thanks

Comment: You could match the same subpattern instead of the captured text itself [`^I like (blue|red). Do you like (?1)\?$`](https://regex101.com/r/72Jchl/7)

Comment: This does not work with all regex flavors.
I like (blue|red)\. Do you like (blue|red)\?
is more general

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to specify what environment or programming language you are using. PCRE, Perl, and .NET support recursive subpatterns, so for example, this will work in PHP but not JavaScript.

```
I like (blue|red)\. Do you like (?1)\?
```